# Parsing XML data fails unexpectedly

Tags: android, xml, textview

I'm currently trying to parse data from a xml using dynamically. So I'm trying to retrieve data via different tags and insert them into different textviews using SimpleAdapter. But its failing when in my point of view, its supposed to work. Please help me figure this out.

This is my **SearchResults.java**:

```
public class SearchResult extends ListActivity{

String set_number;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    //retrieve text passed from previous activity
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String searchItems = bundle.getString("searchItems");

    //get the xml data using retrieve text from previous activity      
    String xmlSetNo = XMLFunctions.getSetNoXML(searchItems);
    Document docSetNo = XMLFunctions.XMLfromString(xmlSetNo);//change xml data to doc format

    NodeList nodeSetNo = docSetNo.getElementsByTagName("find");

    for (int i = 0; i < nodeSetNo.getLength(); i++) {                           
        Element e = (Element)nodeSetNo.item(i);
        set_number = XMLFunctions.getValue(e, "set_number");
    }       

    String xmlRecords = XMLFunctions.getRecordsXML(set_number);
    Document docRecords = XMLFunctions.XMLfromString(xmlRecords);

    NodeList nodeRecords = docRecords.getElementsByTagName("metadata");

    for(int i = 0; i < nodeRecords.getLength(); i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    

        Element e = (Element)nodeRecords.item(i);

        //map.put("cover_image", getTagValue("varfield id='20'", e));
        map.put("title", getTagValue("varfield id='245'", e));
        map.put("author", getTagValue("varfield id='100'", e));
        map.put("format", getTagValue("fixfield id='FMT'", e));
        map.put("call_number", getTagValue("varfield id='099'", e));
        /*
        map.put("set_number", XMLFunctions.getValue(e, "set_number"));
        map.put("no_records", "No. of Records:" + XMLFunctions.getValue(e, "no_records"));
        map.put("no_entries", "No. of Entries: " + XMLFunctions.getValue(e, "no_entries"));
        mylist.add(map);
        */
    }

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.search_result_display_list, 
                    new String[] { "cover_image","title","author","format","call_number"}, 
                    new int[] {R.id.cover_image, R.id.item_title, R.id.item_author,R.id.item_format,R.id.item_call_number });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    final ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
    /*lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   
            Toast.makeText(SearchResult.this, "ID '" + o.get("id") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

        }
    });*/
}

 private static String getTagValue(String sTag, Element eElement){
        NodeList nlList= eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0).getChildNodes();
        Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0); 

        return nValue.getNodeValue();    
     }
}
```

This is my **XMLFunctions.java** where I parse my xml data:

```
public class XMLFunctions {

public final static Document XMLfromString(String xml){

    Document doc = null;

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
        doc = db.parse(is); 

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        System.out.println("XML parse error: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        System.out.println("Wrong XML file structure: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("I/O exeption: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

    return doc;

}

/** Returns element value
  * @param elem element (it is XML tag)
  * @return Element value otherwise empty String
  */
 public final static String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
     Node kid;
     if( elem != null){
         if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
             for( kid = elem.getFirstChild(); kid != null; kid = kid.getNextSibling() ){
                 if( kid.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                     return kid.getNodeValue();
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     return "";
 }

 public static String getSetNoXML(String searchItems){   
        String line = null;

        try {

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            //request for item's set_number
            HttpGet requestSetNumber = new HttpGet("http://spark.opac.tp.edu.sg/X?op=find&scan_code=find_wrd&request="+ searchItems +"&base=tpl01");

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(requestSetNumber);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            line = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            line = "<find status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></find>";
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            line = "<find status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></find>";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            line = "<find status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></find>";
        }
        return line;
}

 public static String getRecordsXML(String setNumber){   
        String line = null;

        try {

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            //request records via set_number
            HttpGet requestRecords = new HttpGet("http://spark.opac.tp.edu.sg/X?op=present&set_no="+ setNumber +"&set_entry=000000001,000000002,000000003," +
                    "000000004,000000005,000000006,000000007,000000008,000000009,000000010&format=marc");


            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(requestRecords);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            line = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            line = "<find status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></find>";
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            line = "<find status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></find>";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            line = "<find status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></find>";
        }
        return line;
}

public static int numResults(Document doc){     
    Node results = doc.getDocumentElement();
    int res = -1;

    try{
        res = Integer.valueOf(results.getAttributes().getNamedItem("find").getNodeValue());
    }catch(Exception e ){
        res = -1;
    }

    return res;
}

public static String getValue(Element item, String str) {       
    NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
    return XMLFunctions.getElementValue(n.item(0));
}
}
```

Lastly, this is the output from **LogCat**:

> 04-25 10:20:15.932: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(418): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   04-25 10:20:15.932: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(418): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{joel.TPLibrary/joel.TPLibrary.SearchResult}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   04-25 10:20:15.932: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(418):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
>   04-25 10:20:15.932: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(418):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>   04-25 10:20:15.932: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(418):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
>   04-25 10:20:15.932: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(418):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>   04-25 10:20:15.932: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(418):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   04-25 10:20:15.932: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(418):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   04-25 10:20:15.932: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(418):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>   04-25 10:20:15.932: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(418):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   04-25 10:20:15.932: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(418):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   04-25 10:20:15.932: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(418):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   04-25 10:20:15.932: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(418):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>   04-25 10:20:15.932: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(418):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   04-25 10:20:15.932: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(418): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   **04-25 10:20:15.932: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(418):     at joel.TPLibrary.SearchResult.getTagValue(SearchResult.java:89)
>
>   04-25 10:20:15.932: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(418):     at joel.TPLibrary.SearchResult.onCreate(SearchResult.java:58)**
>   04-25 10:20:15.932: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(418):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   04-25 10:20:15.932: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(418):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
>   04-25 10:20:15.932: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(418):     ... 11 more

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are going about parsing XML in android the wrong way. Frankly the code looks much more messy than it needs to be.

Instead I would recommended using the annotation based XML framework called [Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) which will help you to write and output XML easily: I like it so much that [I even wrote a blog post about how to include it in your Android projects](http://massaioli.homelinux.com/wordpress/2011/04/21/simple-xml-in-android-1-5-and-up/).

If you provide some example XML then I can give you more info on what is going wrong.

Comment: Hi, I realise that I'm using the DOM Parser when I should be using SAX Parser because I'm only reading data off an xml. So I changed to SAX Parser but currently facing problem on how to retrieve all data under a single tag.