# Parse xml data into hashtable and displaying in listview?

Tags: android, xml, listview, hashtable, sax

I have a problem. I have multiple records that after SAX parsing from a xml file that needs to be inserted into the Hashtable and displayed in a listview. I am able to display the data in the listview but all it gives is the same data for all rows in the listview. I think it has something to do with either my coding for the hashtable or my SAX parsing.

This is the xml file I'm trying to retrieve data from online:  http://spark.opac.tp.edu.sg/X?op=present&set_no=007584&set_entry=000000001,000000002,000000003,000000004,000000005&format=marc

Below is my handler where i place my data into the hashtable:

```
ArrayList<Hashtable<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<Hashtable<String,String>>();

Hashtable<String,String> data = new Hashtable<String,String>();

private final String MY_DEBUG_TAG = "Debugging~";

private Boolean in_record = false;
private Boolean in_author = false;
private Boolean in_format = false;
private Boolean in_title = false;
private Boolean in_callNumber = false;

private String format = "";
private String title = "";
private String author = "";
private String callNumber = "";

//private SearchList sList;

//public SearchList getListData() {
//  return this.sList;
//}

@Override
public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
 //       this.sList = new SearchList();
}

@Override
public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
        // Nothing to do
}

/** Called when tag starts ( ex:- <name>AndroidPeople</name> 
 * -- <name> )*/
@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("record")) {
        this.in_record = true;
    }
    else
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("fixfield")) {
            if (attributes.getValue("id").equalsIgnoreCase("FMT")) {
               this.in_format = true;
            } 
        }
        else
            if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("varfield")) {
                if(attributes.getValue("id").equalsIgnoreCase("100")) {
                    this.in_author = true;
                }
                else
                    if(attributes.getValue("id").equalsIgnoreCase("245")) {
                        this.in_title = true;
                    }
                    else 
                        if(attributes.getValue("id").equalsIgnoreCase("099")) {
                            this.in_callNumber = true;
                        }
            }
}

public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
throws SAXException {

       StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
       String finalString;
       String originalString = "";

       String chars = new String(ch, start, length); 
       chars = chars.trim(); 

       if (this.in_format) {
           sb.append(chars);
           finalString = sb.toString();
           this.format = finalString;
       }
       else
           if (this.in_author) {
               if(!(chars.equals(""))) {
                   sb.append(chars);
                   finalString = sb.toString();
                   originalString = this.author + finalString;
                   this.author = originalString;
               }
           }
           else
               if (this.in_title) {
                   if(!(chars.equals(""))) {
                       sb.append(chars);
                       finalString = sb.toString();
                       originalString = this.title + finalString;
                       this.title = originalString;
                   }
               }          
               else
                   if (this.in_callNumber) {
                       if(!(chars.equals(""))) {
                           sb.append(chars);
                           finalString = sb.toString();
                           this.callNumber = finalString;
                       }
                   }
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {

       if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("record")) {
           this.in_record=false;
       }
       else
           if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("fixfield")) {
               if (this.in_format) {
                  //set the foundCharacter to Hashtable
                  data.put("format", this.format);
                  //sList.setFormat(this.format);
                  Log.d(MY_DEBUG_TAG,"Format = " + this.format);
                  this.in_format = false;
                } 
           }
           else
               if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("varfield")) {
                   if (this.in_author) {
                       //set the foundCharacter to Hashtable
                       data.put("author", this.author);
                       //sList.setAuthor(this.author);
                       Log.d(MY_DEBUG_TAG,"Author = " + this.author);
                       this.in_author = false;
                   }
                   else 
                       if (this.in_title) {
                           //set the foundCharacter to Hashtable
                           data.put("title", this.title);
                           //sList.setTitle(this.title);
                           Log.d(MY_DEBUG_TAG,"Title = " + this.title);
                           this.in_title = false;
                       }
                       else 
                           if (this.in_callNumber) {
                               //set the foundCharacter to Hashtable
                               data.put("callNumber", this.callNumber);
                               //sList.setCallNumber(this.callNumber);
                               Log.d(MY_DEBUG_TAG,"Call Number = " + this.callNumber);
                               this.in_callNumber = false;
                           }
               }
       //add the hashtable into ArrayList        
       list.add(data);
}
```

Any suggestions guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have time to read completly your code ...

But this is a simple example :

```
ListView myListView;
myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylistview);
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listItem = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> map;

//load your data
String[][] items = database.getItems("Blog");

//check if the database was empty
if(items != null){
    for(int i = 0; i < items[0].length; i++) {
        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("pubdate", items[2][0]);
        map.put("title", items[0][i]);
        map.put("description", items[1][i]);
        listItem.add(map);

    }

    //Creation of a SimpleAdapter to put items in your list (listitems) in your listview
    // You need to have a xml file called list_full_news_item with elements
    // called android:id="@+id/title" etc.
    SimpleAdapter mSimpleAdaptor = new SimpleAdapter (this.getBaseContext(), listItem, R.layout.list_full_news_item,
        new String[] {"pubdate", "title", "description"}, new int[] {R.id.itemPubdate, R.id.itemTitle, R.id.itemDescription});
   //Assign to the listView the created adapter
   myListView.setAdapter(mSimpleAdaptor);
}
```

Hope this will help you to understand.

Comment: Thanks ^^. Worked perfectly for me

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the SAX Parser and use the [Simple XML Library](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) instead. It has the [@ElementMap annotation](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/ElementMap.html) for exactly this purpose. This turns your entire problem into one annotation and three lines of code to read the XML in. [Look at my blog post](http://massaioli.homelinux.com/wordpress/2011/04/21/simple-xml-in-android-1-5-and-up/) on including the library in an android project and [look at the Simple tutorial](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php) if you want to see how to use all of its cool features.

**Edit**: I just realised that I have answered this question before in one of your [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774708/parsing-xml-data-fails-unexpectedly). I'm done trying to convince you to look into Simple XML; but please, stop posting essentially the exact same question in five different ways here; people have helped you already, give you answers and lead you in the right direction. It is now time to read more, experiment and learn.